# Xor returns true when two side are true - PHP

Tags: php

As I learned Xor should return false when two variable are true

But I tried it and it doesn't work!

```
$n1 = true;
$n2 = true;
$res = $n1 xor $n2;
echo var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority. Your third statement is evaluated as

```
($res = $n1) xor $n2;
```

I.e. first the assignment happens, and `$res` becomes what `$n1` is (i.e. `true`); the assignment evaluates as the value being assigned, so as the next step `true xor $n2` is evaluated, producing `false`; but this value is not stored or used in any way, and is discarded. Basically, your code is equal to

```
$n1 = true;
$n2 = true;
$res = $n1;
$res xor $n2;        // useless
echo var_dump($res);
```

To expound a bit more, note that there are two sets of logical operators, where the only difference is how tightly they bind. `and`, `or` and `xor` bind very loosely, while their counterparts `&&` and `||` bind tighter. Unfortunately, there is no tight binding counterpart for `xor`. These operators have been brought over from Perl, where a common idiom was to use the loosely-binding operators for flow control:

```
$f = doSomethingThatMightBeFalsy() or die("I failed at my task");
```

which will assign `$f`, and if that value ends up being falsy, die. This is distinct from

```
$f = doSomethingThatMightBeFalsy() || die("I fail evrytym :(");
```

tl;dr: As Akam already wrote, you should explicitly use parentheses to make `xor` bind tighter than the assignment.

Comment: how is that work? $n1 get to the left and make it false?

Comment: `$n1` (`true`) get assigned to `$res`. Then the `xor` operator is performed between that and `$n2` but not assigned to anything.

Answer (score 2):

This because of [PHP Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).
Following example is correct

```
$n1 = true;
$n2 = true;
$res = ($n1 xor $n2);
echo var_dump($res); // bool(false)
```